# autoreleasePool is different in iOS 9?

Tags: ios9, nsautoreleasepool

```
__weak NSString *string_weak_ = nil;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"];
        string_weak_ = string;
    }
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string_weak_);
}
```

`

```
string: (null) // in iPhone(iOS 8.1) simulator
string: hello  // in iPhone(iOS 9.0) simulator
```

I run this code in iPhone(8.1) and iPhone(9.0) simulator.The result is different.
I wonder what happened？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both results are reasonable. The result is implementation-dependent, depending on whether someone else has a reference to the string object returned by the `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` or something, and whether it is even a dynamically-allocated object at all, vs. a statically-allocated object.

String literals evaluate to pointers to statically-allocated objects that exist for the lifetime of the program, and are not memory managed by reference counting. Certain methods, e.g. `[NSString stringWithString:]`, when given an immutable string, simply return the given string, and will not created a new string object, as an optimization.

Here, `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` is used. It's also possible for it to simply return the given format string object, in the case where it's an immutable string and there are no format specifiers. I haven't tested this personally, but perhaps this optimization was added into `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` between OS versions.

Anyway, whether such an optimization exists is implementation-dependent and shouldn't matter to us, because we should never rely on things like whether an object is dynamically-allocated or statically-allocated, or whether there are additional references to it or not.

Comment: but I'm seeing something similar in my app. My memory foot print is very high on iOS 9, whereas on iOS 8 it looks fine (= autorelease pool works how it should)